# Support of Canvas and WebGL (three.js) on moble devices?

Tags: mobile, canvas, webgl, three.js

There's a wonderful 3D-application framework called `three.js`. As far as I understood it has a few render subsystems: based on `Canvas` and based on `WebGL`.

So, what about mobile devices support? (Android, iOS)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regardless of three.js it is broken down like this:

The `Canvas` element can be used with either a `2D` context or a `WebGL` context. threejs can use either the WebGL or the 2D context.

Most mobile phones support the `2D` context.

Few support `WebGL` context yet. Firefox for mobile supports `WebGL` and is available for at least some android builds, and the BlackBerry PlayBook can use it too.

See:

http://caniuse.com/canvas (aka 2D)

http://caniuse.com/webgl

Answer (score 5):

**Update 12-12-2014**
http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl

- IOS8 will have WebGL enabled.
- Android browsers have WebGl enabled.
- However, if you want to create an app, you can use [Crosswalk](http://crosswalk-project.org) to run the app on the latest Chromium (which has WebGL enabled).
- Alternatively, [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) has "Canvas+", which is a native android/iOS implementation of the Canvas element, including a virtual javascript environment. (In other words, a custom browser which can only render Canvas elements)

Comment: WebGL is now supported on All android browsers, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl

Comment: No, old Androids still have the outdated stock browser installed! From Android 5, it seems as if the browser is auto-updated (no need for crosswalk)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Three.js on mobile, at least iOS and only using CanvasRenderer of three.js.
WebGLRenderer won't work on iOS.

Try not to use textures, it slows a lot the framerate.

With simple colored meshes, it's working pretty well and it's fast.

I had a few tests with animated Geometry, primitives only though.

I could test it on iPodTouch 1G and iPodTouch 4G. Both worked well, with good framerate.

I couldn't try it on Android, but I think it's working too.